# CSS File in subforlder of theme not working wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I asked this after searching lots but any tricks and answer not working. i am new and created own custom theme. i upload custom font awesome in my theme directory as follow

- -Gohilar-font
- --CSS
- ---gohilar-font-embedded.css
- --font
- ---gohilar-font.woff

now the problem is  when i link this css file into my header.php it not linking even i tried all suggestion in many site........however it work correctly in my local computer i.e localhost

i added code of css in header.php as follows under head

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/gohilar-font/css/gohilar-font-embedded.css">
```

if i link http://newser.in/wp-content/themes/Gohilar/gohilar-font/css/gohilar-font-embedded.css not opening currectly and shows 404 error

Comment: Could it be that your new server is case-sensitive? i.e. "Gohilar-font" is not the same as "gohilar-font"... But definitely if your link does not work in your browser, it will not work in a css file. So you need to figure out the correct URL path to your font css file... Another thing you need to check is, in "gohilar-font-embedded.css", how do you include/import the actual font "gohilar-font.woff" ?

Comment: case sensitive! That's I never thoughts about that.......you are right..now it works  now I take care that I never mistake again......thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to include css files is to make use of the wp_enqueue_style. Just add the following code to your function.php and adjust the file name and path.

```
// load bootstrap css
wp_enqueue_style( '_tk-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: Ok I do that..... Remove from header.php and add to function.php as per your code ...thank you  for that